# How to Paypals IPN on a local machine with MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

What's the best way to test the IPN service without having access to an IIS server, just on my local machine. Is there any free, simple IIS server software that would let me put the website public to test it or what?

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you running?  You can install IIS on any Pro version of Windows.

Comment: Windows 8 - I've worked with C# for a while but it's the first time I've worked with MVC. Can you make the IIS server public easily?

Comment: Sure.  You just need to open up port 80 on your router and firewall so that it can be accessed by the public, and then I would recommend setting up some sort of DNS that points to your IP address there so you can use a domain name.